# pkcs11interop Get error code from exception

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, pkcs11interop

I have two cards with different types of tokens. When calling `GetTokenInfo()` I get `CKR_TOKEN_NOT_RECOGNIZED` on some tokens. My question is, how do I retrieve this error code in a clean manner?

[image: Snapshot of exception]

HResult just indicates General Error.
I could check for the exception in the Message string.
The `RV` parameter is not part of the `Exception` class, not sure which derivative class to use to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to add a `using Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common;`

Now I am catching `Pkcs11Exception` and retrieving the error code through the `RV` parameter, and comparing it against PKCS#11 error code.

Hope this can help others.

Comment: Nice question and correct answer. I tuned markdown formatting of them both to improve reading experience. Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted.